# Can low integrity process create a named mutant object?

Tags: windows, winapi, synchronization, mutex

I'm trying to create a new named mutant from a low integrity process. This code works great on a high integrity process, but fails on low and medium integrity.

```
RtlInitUnicodeString(&Name, L"\\MutantName");
InitializeObjectAttributes(&Attr, &Name, OBJ_INHERIT | OBJ_OPENIF, NULL, NULL);
NTStatus = NtCreateMutant(&Mutant, MUTANT_ALL_ACCESS, &Attr, 0);
```

I'm getting `NTStatus = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0xc0000022)`.

Is it possible to create a mutant from a low integrity process? If yes - does someone know what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Low Integrity process can create objects only in an object directory that has a Low Mandatory label. The root object directory does not have this label. `\BaseNamedObjects` does, so you can create your mutant in there from a Low Integrity process:

```
RtlInitUnicodeString(&Name, L"\\BaseNamedObjects\\MutantName");
```